# Java List containsAll returning false?

Tags: java

This is returning false....im expecting true

```
 List<String> listA // [941,  946,  940,  942]
 List<String>  listB //[941, 942, 940, 946,888, 466, 777]

listB.containsAll(listA) //FALSE ??
```

Comment: is that whitespace accurate?

Comment: Its a comma separated list of strings....whitespace is just in the comment

Comment: right, but you don't have quotes around your strings and so I am wondering if the whitespace is considered part of the string or not.

Comment: Give us a reproducible example.

Comment: Please provide the complete code with proper variable initialization.

Comment: Obviously, there's not a JDK bug that has been unnoticed for over 10 years. The problem is in the data. Check properly your input, look for whitespace and/or unprintable characters. Go element by element and try `contains()` on it to see which one is missong and why.

Comment: It works for me http://ideone.com/jYAimV

Comment: Check `if (listA.get(0) == listB.get(0))`. I believe `containsAll` checks object references, not equality i.e. `.equals()`.

Comment: It definitely uses `.equals`

Comment: @2rs2ts It uses `equals()`. See the docs for [`contains()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29).

Comment: @Slanec Thanks, I was under the wrong assumption. I had double checked just the doc for `containsAll()` and didn't see anything about that, oops.

Comment: On an unrelated note, when you're using `contains()` and/or `containsAll()`, consider using a `Set<String>` instead of a `List<String>`. After you have resolved your issue, that is.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up fellas...it mos def was the white space

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`false` result means that some values in `listA` do not have corresponding (equal) values in `listB`. It may be caused by some unnecessary whitespaces. You need to know that

```
"foo".equals(" foo")
```

will return `false` which means used values are not equal, because space also count as characters.

---

If each string is properly formatted, the sample data you have provided works just fine.

```
import  java.util.Arrays;
import  java.util.List;

public class Test  {
   public static final void main(String[] ignored)  {
     List<String> listA = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"941", "946", "940", "942"});
     List<String> listB = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"941", "942", "940", "946", "888", "466", "777"});

     System.out.println(listB.containsAll(listA));
   }
}
```

Output: `true`

Comment: Why in the heck would this be downvoted?

Comment: lol..I dunno man....these dudes funny

Comment: @aliteralmind Probably because it is essentially [works for me](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118992/are-works-for-me-answers-valid) comment, not an answer (you didn't explain what OP did wrong).

Comment: I'm not intending it as an answer. Just as a confirmation of what was stated in the comments. This is *not* the answer, and shouldn't be accepted as such. But a down-vote I don't think is appropriate either.

Comment: @Pshemo: Clarified my answer to be a non-answer. Should I just delete it?

Comment: Any vote here is not appropriate to be hones, because this shouldn't be posted an answer...

Comment: IMHO you should, but now you can't because OP accepted it. Only way to delete it is now by unaccepting it by OP, or downvoting it to let users with lot more reputation vote to delete it.

Comment: @DocHoliday: I appreciate the support, but this needs to be deleted. Please unaccept.

Comment: @DocHoliday Or even better update your question and add code which would let us reproduce your problem. This way aliteralmind would be able to improve his post and make it actual answer.

Comment: NP. I don't want to downvote you so for now I will only downvote question and vote to close it. If OP will not improve his question I will vote to delete it so your answer will also be deleted. Lets hope OP will come back with better code.

Comment: I edited your answer a little to add more informations about possible source of the problem, then fact that this should work. Hope you don't mind. In case there are some grammar mistakes (English is not my native language and I only use it here on SO) feel free to correct them ^^

Comment: Thank you for doing it. It looks good to me. If you're okay with it, then, I'll eliminate the comments relating to this not being an answer, and the request for deleting it (...which I'm surprised was left unanswered...).